# Select query never finishes first time, then when rerun finishes instantly

Tags: sql-server

On my current project we have a very strange issue with a select query against our sql server database.

The first time we run the query after deploying it never finishes. Then, if we stop the query and rerun it, it finishes instantly.

We have nothing else running when we issue the query the first time, so I can't see how it can be dead lock related.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Here is the query for reference:

```
SELECT KontoplanKommuneAar.fk_kontoplankommune_id_kontoplankommune, 
       KontoplanKommuneAar.kontoplankommuneaarid, 
       KontoplanKommuneAar.fk_kontoplanindividuel_id_kontoplanindividuel, 
       KontoplanKommuneAar.sys_kommuneid, 
       KontoplanKommuneAar.sys_extractdate, 
       KontoplanKommuneAar.sys_batchdate 
FROM   (SELECT kka.fk_kontoplankommune_id_kontoplankommune, 
               kka.kontoplankommuneaarid, 
               kka.fk_kontoplanindividuel_id_kontoplanindividuel, 
               kka.sys_kommuneid, 
               kka.sys_batchdate, 
               kka.sys_rowid, 
               kka.sys_extractdate 
        FROM   edw.dbo.kontoplankommuneaar kka 
        WHERE  kka.kontoplankommuneaarid != -1 
               AND ( kka.kontoplankommuneaarid IN (SELECT 
                           fk_kontoplankommuneaar_id_kontoplankommuneaar 
                                                   FROM 
                     kontoplanposteringsummaaned) 
                      OR kka.kontoplankommuneaarid IN (SELECT 
                         fk_kontoplankommuneaar_id_kontoplankommuneaar 
                                                       FROM 
                         kontoplanbudgetvedtaget) 
                      OR kka.kontoplankommuneaarid IN (SELECT 
                         fk_kontoplankommuneaar_id_kontoplankommuneaar 
                                                       FROM 
                         kontoplankorrigeringbudget) )) KontoplanKommuneAar 
ORDER  BY KontoplanKommuneAar.fk_kontoplankommune_id_kontoplankommune
```

Comment: You should use joins in your query. That would make it easier to read... Not saying it because of performance though

Comment: Can you share the schema of the tables involved as well? maybe a small fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT  kka.fk_kontoplankommune_id_kontoplankommune
    ,   kka.kontoplankommuneaarid
    ,   kka.fk_kontoplanindividuel_id_kontoplanindividuel
    ,   kka.sys_kommuneid
    ,   kka.sys_batchdate
    ,   kka.sys_extractdate
FROM dbo.kontoplankommuneaar kka
WHERE kka.kontoplankommuneaarid != -1
    AND kka.kontoplankommuneaarid IN
    (
        SELECT fk_kontoplankommuneaar_id_kontoplankommuneaar
        FROM dbo.kontoplanposteringsummaaned

        UNION 

        SELECT fk_kontoplankommuneaar_id_kontoplankommuneaar
        FROM dbo.kontoplanbudgetvedtaget

        UNION

        SELECT fk_kontoplankommuneaar_id_kontoplankommuneaar
        FROM dbo.kontoplankorrigeringbudget 
    )
ORDER BY kka.fk_kontoplankommune_id_kontoplankommune
```

Comment: We have already tried constructing the inner select as a union, it had the same outcome.

Comment: Please provide your execution plan.

Comment: I can give my execution plan tomorrow when it's not working again :)

I was primarily interested in why this happens. Under what circumstances does it help running it and then rerunning it?

Comment: Just restart your `SQL Server`.

Comment: The query is still fast when we reboot the sql server.

I think it might have something to do with the statistics gathering? Maybe it gets updated correctly while running the query the first time but isn't included in the query. Then the second time it works.

Could this be what happens?